# How to chain .html() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet of code which grabs the html inside tfoot of my table (a tr) and stores it so I can use it as a template, then removes it.

```
   $teamTfoot = $teamsTable.find('tfoot');
    tpl = $teamTfoot.html();
    $teamTfoot.html('');
```

I thought I would have been able to do a one liner like this, but obviously that doesn't work.

```
    tpl = $teamsTable.find('tfoot').html().html('');
```

Is what I have done the best/easiest approach to extracting the html?

Comment: Since you are using `.html()` as a getter obviously  you can't chain it. I really don't understand  _this should be one-liner_ philosophy.

Comment: That isn't even logical.

Comment: By one liner, I guess I was trying to say is there a more elegant way of doing this, which the answers from Guffa and undefined have both shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have already is as good as it gets.

It's *possible* to chain commands to get the result, but then you have to store the content somewhere else while you empty the element, so that you can return it at the end:

```
tpl = $teamTfoot.data('tpl', $teamTfoot.html()).empty().data('tpl');
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `.html()` as a getter you can't chain it, if you want to store the value in a variable and set the html content to an empty string you can use `html()`'s callback function.

```
$teamsTable.find('tfoot').html(function(_, htmlContent) {
    tpl = htmlContent;
    return '';  
}); // .foo().bar();
```